# Increase memory limit in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm, nodes

I am trying to increase memory limit in node,
so I added an environment variable

[here is how I did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zbDk.png)

it does not work not sure why I also tried it with capital letters
here is how I test it

```
 const maxHeapSz = require('v8').getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit;
 const maxHeapSz_GB = (maxHeapSz / 1024 ** 3).toFixed(1);
 console.log(`${maxHeapSz_GB}GB`);
```

I keep gettin 2GB, I'm trying to get 8GB

I appreciate any help

Comment: @LawrenceCherone 2GB

Comment: try changing `node_options` to `NODE_OPTIONS` also verify it works using `node --max-old-space-size=8192 your-script.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js
```

It's work for me!

Result:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 test.js 
8.0GB
```

Answer (score 0):

> The actual memory that is consumed by the application (in the form of objects in the JavaScript heap) is represented by heapUsed field in process.memoryUsage() API.

You can check for more information [here](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/nodejs-memory-management-in-container-environments/). This article also shows methods to increase the maximum heap size.